# jaxb xjc compilation error Super Interface not found In jaxb generated class path

Tags: java, gradle, jaxb, gradle-plugin

I am using `rackerlabs/gradle-jaxb-plugin` to generate classes from schema.
I am using a super interface `com.test.xsd.Element`. Using xjb I am configuring the interface.
This interface is in my current project `src/main/java` location.
Jaxb classes generating successfully and Implementing the interface.
But compilation fails with:

```
com.test.xsd" package does not exist.import com.test.xsd.Element.Element;
how we can add this interface to class path.
```

Code:

```
subprojects { project ->
    apply plugin: 'org.openrepose.gradle.plugins.jaxb'
    dependencies {
        jaxb 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-xjc:2.2.7'
        jaxb 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:2.2.7'
        jaxb 'javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.2.7'
    }

    def generatedDir = "${project.buildDir}/generated-sources/xjc"

    jaxb {
        xjc {
            args['-npa']
            extension=true
            destinationDir = "${generatedDir}"
            generateEpisodeFiles=false
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            java {
                srcDirs += "${generatedDir}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finlly done with ant task with gradle.
That is very flexible, I think. we can generate classes from multiple xsds and multiple binding files from different location.

```
org.openrepose.gradle.plugins.jaxb bit difficult to manage
```